# flatten array within a Dataframe in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can i flatten array into dataframe that contain colomns [a,b,c,d,e]

```
root
 |-- arry: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- e: long (nullable = true)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Say, you have a json with the following structure:

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "a": "asdf",
      "b": 1234,
      "c": "a",
      "d": "str",
      "e": 1234
    },
    {
      "a": "asdf",
      "b": 1234,
      "c": "a",
      "d": "str",
      "e": 1234
    },
    {
      "a": "asdf",
      "b": 1234,
      "c": "a",
      "d": "str",
      "e": 1234
    }
  ]
}
```

1. Read the file

```
scala> val nested = spark.read.option("multiline",true).json("nested.json")
nested: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [array: array<struct<a:string,b:bigint,c:string,d:string,e:bigint>>]
```

2. Check the schema

```
scala> nested.printSchema
root
 |-- array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- e: long (nullable = true)
```

3. Use [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) function

```
scala> nested.select(explode($"array").as("exploded")).select("exploded.*").show
+----+----+---+---+----+
|   a|   b|  c|  d|   e|
+----+----+---+---+----+
|asdf|1234|  a|str|1234|
|asdf|1234|  a|str|1234|
|asdf|1234|  a|str|1234|
+----+----+---+---+----+
```